# Django 1.6: How to ping google when sitemap is updated?

Tags: python, django, django-sitemaps

I'm trying to implement Django [sitemaps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/sitemaps/) and want to use the ping google when my sitemap is updated. I'm little confused about how to write the save method in my models whenever a new doctor entry is added to the database.

Here is my models.py file

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1300)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic)
    seekers = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserContent')
    language = models.ManyToManyField(Language)
    scope = models.CharField(max_length=1300, null = True, blank = True)
    education1 = models.CharField(max_length=1300)
    gender_choices = ( ('Male', 'Male'), ('Female','Female'),)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices = gender_choices, null=True, blank = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', null=True, blank = True)
    mimetype = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null = True, blank = True)

def __unicode__(self):
  return u"%s %s" % (self.name, self.specialization)


def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    return reverse('meddy1.views.showDocProfile', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't override the save method. Better, use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/), more specifically, the post_save signal.

Comment: I tried doing post_save(ping_google('/sitemap.xml'), sender=Doctor, dispatch_uid=DOCTOR_PING_GOOGLE) but I get an HTTP Error 400: Bad Request